# How can I execute a Oracle Stored Procedure with jOOQ?

Tags: jooq

I get the name of a stored procedure as a configuration value and want to execute this procedure with some parameters using jOOQ.

Unfortunately I didn't find a method on the DSLContext like execute() or something.

How can I call a stored procedure using a string in jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [more info on the generated stubs for stored procedures, see also this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/).

On the generated code of your stored procedure, you can use either one of two approaches. If your procedure is

```sql
PROCEDURE p (i VARCHAR2, o OUT VARCHAR2);
```

#### Call the static method

For every procedure, there's a static method being generated in the `Routines` class, if it is a standalone procedure, or in a class named after your package if it is a package level class. You can call that procedure as follows:

```java
String o = Routines.p(configuration, i);
```

The result type is:

- `void` if there are no `OUT` parameters, and no return values
- `T` if there is a single `OUT` parameter or return value of type `T`
- `<RoutineName>` (a wrapper type) if there are more than one `OUT` parameter or return value

#### Call the wrapper type

The above static method is just a helper method to write the glue code around the routine wrapper type, which has been generated for each routine. You can also call this sequence of methods:

```java
P p = new P();
p.setI(i);
p.execute();
String o = p.getO();
```

This corresponds to the contents of the static method. It is the preferred way of using the routine when there are overloads or default parameters.

#### Not using the code generator

jOOQ currently doesn't support calling stored procedures without using the code generator through public API. You could implement your own `AbstractRoutine` (just like generated code), but then why not just use code generation.

You can obviously call a stored procedure using plain SQL, e.g.

```java
ctx.execute("DECLARE o VARCHAR2(10); BEGIN o := p(?); END;", i);
```

But there is currently no way of declaring (or retrieving) an `OUT` parameter to plain SQL statements.

The relevant feature request is https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3426

Comment: And how do I get the return value when I call ctx.execute?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: There's no difference in JDBC between a "return value" and an "OUT parameter". As mentioned there is currently no way of declaring (nor retrieving) `OUT` parameters in plain SQL statements.

Comment: Oh now I understand. Thanks